# Can I make a VectorPlot with a domain defined by an InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I'd like to plot a vector field in a custom domain; I can do this using ImplicitRegion and a straightforward function. However, when I replace the function with an InterpolatingFunction I get a VectorPlot error. By way of example, here is a simple function

`func[xx_] := 1.5 - 0.5*xx^2`

and I reproduce it as an InterpolatingFunction

`funcint = Interpolation[Table[{x, func[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]];`.

It is easy enough to plot the former as a VectorPlot:

`VectorPlot[{1, 0}, {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[y <= func[x], {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1.5}}]]`,

[image: successful vectorplot]

but when I try to do it with the latter,

`VectorPlot[{1, 0}, {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[y <= funcint[x], {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1.5}}]]`,

I get this error:

`VectorPlot::idomdim: {x,y}\[Element]ImplicitRegion[y<=funcint[x],{{x,0,1},{y,0,1.5}}] does not have a valid dimension as a plotting domain.`

How can I fix this? Is it even possible to plot with the domain defined by an interpolating function? Thanks!

Comment: It seeems that `ImplicitRegion` has limited functionality when using numerical functions in it. One option which seems to work in this case is to discretize the implicit region: `VectorPlot[{1,0},{x,y}\[Element]DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[y<=funcint[x],{{x,0,1},{y,0,1.5}}]]` could be a starting point.

Comment: @N0va, thanks this has helped! Still a little confusing, because I can show a RegionPlot using ImplicitRegion and a numerical function: `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[y <= funcint[x], {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1.5}}]]` works fine.